# Building html tables from query data... faster?

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table

With my limited experience/knowledge I am using the following structure to generate HTML tables on the fly from MySQL queries:

```
$c = 0;
$t = count($results);

$table = '<table>';

while ($c < $t) {
   $table .= "<tr><td>$results[0]</td><td>$results[1]</td> (etc etc) </tr>";
   ++$c;
}

$table .= '</table>';
```

this works, obviously. But for tables with 300+ rows there is a noticeable delay in pageload while the script builds the table. Currently the maximum results list is only about 1,100 rows, and the wait isn't long, but there's clearly a wait.

Are there other methods for outputting an HTML table that are faster than my WHILE loop? (PHP only please...)

Comment: Musing - would it, from the user's perspective, be better to close a table and open a new one with no headers after say... every 50 rows? so that they get results displayed in their field of view almost immediately and extra results are filled in offscreen while they look at the first chunk? Doesn't HTML require a table to be "finished" before it displays? This might be a ghetto-fabulous work around of the "marching morons" variety...

Comment: Have you profiled your app to make sure where it is slow? Most of the time, the bottleneck is the database connection.

Comment: I have. The query, though occasionally heavy on left joins depending on user-selected parameters, comes back lickety-split. The database is well-built and thoroughly indexed. It's blowing the data out to an HTML table that's taking "forever" ... If only I could just VAR_DUMP or print_r and be done with it... ;-)

Comment: Andrew: the "must finish table before it can be displayed" line applied to old-school browsers, like Netscape <= 4.x, which couldn't reflow content. A modern HTML rendering engine is perfectly capable of spitting out a table on the fly and redrawing it as needed as it encounters new columns/spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there other methods for outputting an HTML table that are faster than my WHILE loop?

Potentially yes. PHP is a templating language. Use it as such, don't fight it! Native templating is likely to be faster than laboriously sticking strings together manually — and IMO more readable.

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($results as $result) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result[0]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result[1]); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

(Note the use of `htmlspecialchars`. If you don't use this function *every time* you insert plain text into HTML, your code has HTML-injection flaws, leading to potential cross-site-scripting vulnerabilities. You can define a function with a short name like `h` to do `echo htmlspecialchars` to avoid some typing, but you *must* HTML-encode your strings.)

However: whilst this is prettier and more secure, it is unlikely to be significantly faster in practice. Your client-side rendering slowness is almost certainly going to be caused more by:

1. network transmission speeds for a lot of table data. You can improve this by deploying with `zlib.output_compression`, `mod_deflate` or other compressing filter for your web server, if you have not already.
2. rendering speeds for large tables. You can improve this by setting the CSS style `table-layout: fixed` on your `<table>` element and adding `<col>` elements with explicit `width` styles for the columns you want to have a fixed width.

Comment: `you must HTML-encode your strings` This doesn't apply if the MySQL columns are `datetime` or `int`, for instance, and would unnecessarily _increase_ load times.

Comment: @rybo111: Your markup layer should not need to know where a string variable comes from and what limitations there are on the characters in it. Omitting escaping in places you think it is 'safe' will come back to bite you when you change the application to make that assumption no longer valid. Templates that *always* HTML-escape when writing text to HTML are easier to maintain, reason about, and detect newly-added security holes in. HTML-escaping is inexpensive; except for cases where you are explicitly dealing with already-encoded markup, there is no good reason not to do it.

Answer (score 6):

First, probably the slowness is a result of the HTML rendering and not the PHP script.
Second, it is not very usable to build very large tables it is better to use paging.

You can  improve your script performance in the PHP side in a few ways:

1. use ob_start(); and ob_get_clean(); - this way the data will be passed to the html at once:

   ```
   ob_start();
   // your code here
   echo ob_get_clean();
   ```
2. use array and join for strings:

   ```
   $str = array();
   $str[] = 'add the strings';
   echo implode($str);
   ```

BR.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd try is - don't concatenate your strings. In every language I have used there has always been a bit of a performance penalty for continually adding strings together and spitting out one huge string at the end.

Try using multiple `echo` statements instead, if you can.

Another one to try - based on my own experience, I'm pretty sure a  `for` loop (**not** `for each`) is faster than a `while`. I'm afraid I have no numbers or proof to back that up, just what I've observed over the years.

Comment: True, but these are micro-optimzations that yield no substantial improvement. See http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: I think this rather relates to memory consumption than raw speed, indeed foreach is slower but it's so little it's hardly noticable, foreach does however create a copy of the iterable object/array in memory so memory usage increases.

Answer (score 1):

This is browser issue, not PHP. 
Save your table into HTML and open it - the result would be the same.

Just avoid such huge HTML tables. I'd suggest to use some pagination, i.e. to split your table into smaller pages, like SO doing with questions list

Answer (score 0):

This might be a step in the right direction.

http://eaccelerator.net/

Comment: @Andrew On one of my projects I got a similar problem. Huge Table with many cells. Just using an OpCode cache gretly sped up things. That's not yet page or query caching. Just the OpCodes. With query caching, I got another huge improvement and caching cells with expensive to render content yielded some more percent.

Answer (score 0):

load it from a xml file. Below is the logic .

You know when a table gets updated. When a table gets updated Write all that has to be displayed in a xml file.When a user loads the page load data from the xml file. This way you do not have to run queries and iterate loops when user is loading the page. It is faster this way. check and post back if it works.

If you feel the above logic is still slow and you have even more data do the following - 
When the page loads first load 100 tables data. Then fire a ajax request and get the next 100 nodes from xml file and display it. Once this is finished again fire a ajax request get the next 100 nodes from the xml file and show it in the page and so on..

Comment: Perhaps I should have noted that these are customized search results that will have different content, different headers, and even different #s of columns from query to query depending on the users' preference. In this way, I don't think writing to a static file and updating as needed is suitable, as it would literally have to be updated every single time.

Comment: Then i think you should not be loading 300 + table data. Instead draw only 100 tables and give a more link let the user know from the interface that there are more results for the query and that they have to click the more button.

Comment: do it the way twitter does "More" button at the bottom of the page